# how to get web extension icon to call javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I try to create a simple firefox web extension.
As a first try i thought I want to just get some alert box when the extension button is clicked

I created this manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "FirstExt",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "first script",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon-38.png",
    "default_title": "My first extension"
  } 
}
```

and in background.js:

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){ alert("hello"); });
```

I tried changing it to `console.log` but get no output. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert` is [disabled from background pages in WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#Additional_incompatibilities).

> Firefox does not support using `alert()`, `confirm()`, or `prompt()` from background pages.

Your console output probably works, but you need to be looking in the correct (background) console - not the currently displayed tab's console.

See the [MDN documentation on debugging background pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging#Debugging_background_scripts) ― the console is accessible through `about:debugging` page.